# Java Applet crashes .NET Webbrowsercontrol

Tags: java, browser, applet, controls

in our application we have a Java applet running inside a .NET browser control. It is a know issue from Sun that running an applet this way may crash the control.

Has anyone come across the same problem and solved it?

Atm we are running the applet in a Webbrowser but we need to run it in a browser control.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time the problem solved itself.
It was indeed a bug in the java runtime which is now fixed by sun. Just make sure your JRE is > 1.6.10.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the applet and have source, then you could try to migrate the Java Applet to a J# Browser control and stuff that in your .net application.

```
Here is a link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290083(VS.71).aspx
```